# Proving that a projected line on a given plane includes given point.

Tags: geometry

[image: diagram]

As can be seen in the image, we have lines that are projected on a plane. The original lines are in the xy-plane and also in parallel with the x-axis. The lines are projected through the point (0,0,1), and the plane where the lines are projected has the equation $ax + by = -\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. The plane is in parallel with the z-axis and has the distance 1 from the origin.

Now, the problem is to prove that all projected lines go through the point $(\dfrac{-\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{a}, 0, 1)$.

I tried doing it with basic linear algebra methods but came at a stop. This is from a course in projective geometry so I think I need to use homogeneous coordinates somehow, but I'm really not sure how to do it. I don't want to sound like I haven't tried solving it, because I really have, and I've read the whole course summary and I understand most of it but I don't really know how to approach this problem. Math doesn't come that easy for me and I would really benefit from an explanation here, and I'm not asking for the answer but rather some help on how I should approach the problem.